# How to set up Canon LBP3000 shared from Windows 7?

Tags: networking, windows, 64-bit, printing, canon

Ok, so I've got Canon LBP3000 attached to my HTPC/home server running Windows 7 x64. It's shared over the network and other Windows PCs can access it and use it without any problems.

Recently, I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on my main work PC (it's a Toshiba Tecra laptop), and I'm mostly happy with how things are going, but I've got absolutely no idea how to set up my printer. I've searched and found some solutions (mostly for 32-bit unfortunately), but none of them are detailed enough and/or I don't have enough knowledge to pick the important bits and figure out the rest.

I've downloaded the drivers from Canon website. Please, someone, step by step, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

I have a computer that I am trying to troubleshoot and in the process I have a network in the house and it is a Windows network. I run Win7 on my main computer and out of curiosity I attempted to install my Canon MP500 in order to print from this computer that I am troubleshooting.

I went to Settings, selected printers, then add. After going through the questions that it asked about what the computers share name was, it asked about what kind on printer. I ran through the list that was built into the Ubuntu OS and found the MP500, and then I asked it to install and it found the printer, (which is shared in the network), and installed the drivers that it needed and then allowed me to print a test sheet that came out perfectly. The total time that it took to install the printer was probably five minutes or less, and the version of Ubuntu is 12.10 with the rest of the network on various levels of Windows from XP to W'7. I am not sure what process that you are trying to use, but that is how I installed my Canon, and it was pretty straightforward. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to install canon lbp 3000 printer in a ubuntu 11.10 over a lan 
connection from a computer having windows connected directly to
the printer.
Note the Following models are supported 
LBP2900
LBP3000
LBP3100/3108/3150
LBP3200
LBP3250
LBP3300
LBP3310
LBP3500
im using a ubuntu 11.10 system 32 bit

you can use my ideas as a base if your actual requirements differ

64bit is also supported accordingly.

You need to have Gdebi installer istalled in your system to simplify the process
if you dont have then please install Gdebi installer first.
Gdebi installer helps to install deb files.

If you know another way to install deb files you may proceed.

Steps to install Canon printer over a network from another computer
downlad the tar.gz file approx 60 mb

http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100004596/03/Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz
extract it in a folder of your choice name

browse inside

go to the folder 32bitdriver/debian/
(note 64bit driver is also available in this compressed file )

install capt drivers using gdebi installer

strictly in the following order

cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb
cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386

restart linux

start terminal
type
sudo system-config-printer
give password when asked
press add
select network printer
select windows printer via samba
click browse
locate the computer 
click the printer canon lbp3000

click forward

follow the onscreen commands .

you are done

you may print a test page